# c# get string without escape characters from url

Tags: c#

This is my string

```
string link = "http%3A%2F%2Feurocommunicator.ge%2Fgeo%2Fview_myth%2F229"
```

I want to get absolute uri but it throws exception that uri is invalid :

```
  Uri uri = new Uri(link);
```

What's wrong in this sting? 
i want to get something like this :

```
http://eurocommunicator.ge/geo/view_myth/229
```

Comment: you need [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Not works, i've tried it before but string is the same : "http%3A%2F%2Feurocommunicator.ge%2Fgeo%2Fview_myth%2F229".

Comment: @user3857731 what you need is `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` I think, not `Encode`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
string decodedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx

Works like a charm in linqpad

```
void Main()
{
    var url="http%3A%2F%2Feurocommunicator.ge%2Fgeo%2Fview_myth%2F229";
    string decodedUrl = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedUrl);
}
```

Comment: It has the same string  : "http%3A%2F%2Feurocommunicator.ge%2Fgeo%2Fview_myth%2F229"

Comment: check my edit you can try using `UnescapeDataString`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://eurocommunicator.ge/geo/view_myth/229");
```

or

```
string link = "http%3A%2F%2Feurocommunicator.ge%2Fgeo%2Fview_myth%2F229"
Uri uri = new Uri(Server.UrlDecode(link));
```

Comment: Additional information: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: Have amended accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok my fail `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` works fine, i was using `HtmlDecode` instead of it. How stupid am i